# upgrading specs2 version leads to an error

Tags: specs2

I upgraded specs2 version from 2.4.12 -> 3.8.9 and when I run a test an error has been occured : 
[error] the pandoc executable is not available at: pandoc
[error] Error: Total 6, Failed 4, Errors 1, Passed 1

Has someone idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Specs2 version 3 is using [`pandoc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc) to produce HTML reports. This is explained in [this post](https://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2014/12/specs2-three.html) which presents the main changes between version 2 and 3.

You can also pass the `!pandoc` flag on the command-line if you don't want to install `pandoc` on your machine (see the HTML output arguments in the [User Guide](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.6.0/org.specs2.guide.HtmlOutput.html)).

Comment: I don't like to use pandoc . Have you idea how Can I change in the build.sbt to do that because I run my tests in the jenkins

Comment: You can try to pass `-Dspecs2.pandoc=false` or `sbt testOnly * -- !pandoc`